# Shell script read problem

Tags: gnome, scripts

I'm trying to create a shell script with a `read` command, so that when I run the script, it will ask the user a yes- or no-question. If the user types `yes`, the script continues, and if she writes `no` it stops.

What is the syntax for using the `read` command in such a way?

I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: 13.04 is end of life please upgrade; we are also not a coding site but I would not advice asking this on http://stackoverflow.com/ Here is a starter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script

Comment: This also barely has anything to do with Ubuntu. This is just standard shell scripting, or in the case of some answers below, with bash extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be better served by the `select` command, which allows the user to select an option that's presented to them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Are you sure?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) break;;
        No ) exit;;
    esac
done

# Add whatever you want to do if the user answered "yes" here
```

If the user answered "No", the script will exit without executing the code further down the script.

The only downside to using `select` is that the options are selected using numbers. So because we have two options, the user can't type "Yes", they have to type "1", etc.

Answer (score 1):

All your bash -programming questions in one go: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html - find "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide".

It contains a lot of examples, very easy to read ;-) 
- I have had some pauses in my bash usage from time to time and have therefore used it as a dictionary.

Also: bash built in:s like read has help available as in

```
help read
```

and then, a simple answer to your question:

```
echo -n "Y/N - Yes or No :" && read -N 1 ans && echo -e "\r$(tput el)You said $ans."
```

*tput - prints items from the terminfo database. "man terminfo" for more.*

Comment: `on hold` - if questions relating to bash is off topic, then at least let there be pointers off site (e.g. tldp.org above) - unless this is allowed ubuntu specific users might step out of here, and possibly flag the place as unhelpful.